# galera cluster how to run an ALTER without using RSU/TOI

Tags: mariadb, galera, multi-master

I need to run an alter statement but would like to prevent locking/stall the cluster. The [Galera docs](http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/clusterstallonalter.html) advised using:

```
SET wsrep_OSU_method='RSU';
```

Then Run the ALTER statement, once finich:

```
SET wsrep_OSU_method='TOI';
```

Problem is that this needs to be run in every node, and I have only access to one node behind a load balancer, any alternatives or workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSU:  You must bypass the load balancer and go straight to each node in turn.

TOI:  Simply run the `ALTER` on any node.  The downside is that if the `ALTER` takes a long time, it will, as you say, lock/stall the cluster.

gh-ost:  This depends on the binlog, which (I think) is not used in Galera.

pt-online-schema-change:  This requires adding `TRIGGERs` to the table -- perhaps a problem?  And it requires a script to continually talk to the server in question -- will your load balancer allow such?  And it probably wants to treat the system as Master-Slave(s), not Multi-Master -- apparently you have set up Galera set up Multi-Master?

Comment: unfortunately, I can't bypass the load balancer what about using something like https://github.com/github/gh-ost or pt-online-schema-change ?

Comment: @nbari - I don't think either will work.  I added to my Answer, and hope that someone else will comment if I am in error.